Kubuntu wallpaper doesn't stay after reboot
Every time I select one of the default wallpapers from Kubuntu with KDE, it goes back to the default after a reboot in some of my monitors. The entire system is in the same partition.
I'm currently using 22.04.04 LTS with kernel 5.15.0-105-generic. I have three screens connected to my video card, which is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650.
